# Does $(\sqrt{2x^{2}})(\sqrt{6x}) $ simplify to $2x\sqrt{3x}$, or to $2|x|\sqrt{3x}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am having trouble simplifying these expressions.

$$(\sqrt{2x^{2}})(\sqrt{6x}) $$

The textbook states that for n is even

$$|a| = \sqrt[n]{a^n}$$

The answer key says that the answer is

$$ 2x\sqrt{3x}$$

But when I use the rules stated in the textbook, I get

$$ 2|x|\sqrt{3x}$$
because $|a| = \sqrt[n]{a^n}$.

This has happened a couple of times where I simplify to an absolute value variable where the answer key says it's just a variable.

Where am I missing a step?

Comment: I can't understand your question, consider typing it in [MathJax; here's a tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: By "n sqrt(a^n)" do you mean "$\sqrt[n]{a^n}$"? If so, then please use MathJax formatting and write it as `$\sqrt[n]{a^n}$`. Likewise `$\sqrt{2x^2}$` for $\sqrt{2x^2}$, etc. If that "x" between "sqrt(2x^2)" and "sqrt(6x)" should be the multiplication sign, then use `$\times$` for "$\times$" or `$\cdot$` for "$\cdot$".

Comment: As to the question itself ... It appears that (ignoring the numbers) the confusion boils down to whether $\sqrt{x^3}$ is $x\sqrt{x}$ or $|x|\sqrt{x}$. It "should be" $|x|\sqrt{x}$, but consider this: if $x$ were negative, then $x^3$ would be negative, which causes problems for $\sqrt{x^3}$ and $\sqrt{x}$ (until you later learn about imaginary numbers, but I digress ...). So, for the problem to make sense, there's an *implicit assumption* that $x$ is non-negative; in such cases, $|x|=x$, making both you and the book correct. BTW, $\sqrt[n]{a^n}=|a|$ for *even* $n$; for *odd* $n$, it's just $a$.

Comment: @Blue Yes, thank you. Ive updated the post using MathJax

Comment: @Blue Thank you. The question actually states to assume that the variables are non-negative for some questions. That's why I was confused and getting different answers than the textbook. So if I understand correctly, because the question states that we are to assume that the variables are no-negative, then |x| does not make sense in which case we use x?

Comment: @Grant: It's not that $|x|$ *doesn't make sense* for non-negative values. (In my comment, what wouldn't "make sense" is having a negative under the radical.) It's that the absolute value operation *doesn't do anything* to non-negative numbers. $|42|=42$, $|123.456|=123.456$, $|\pi|=\pi$, $|0|=0$. So, it's safe to drop the bars.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both are correct. Since the domain is $x \ge 0$ because of the term $\sqrt{x}$, your answer can be simplified to what stated in the book.